# How to increment OCR1A value in ATmega16 through hardware?

Tags: avr, servo

For my project I am controlling servo motors through ATmega16 micro controller. The OCR1A determines the position of motor.

I want to increment the OCR1A value through a hardware switch. I tried doing it through interrupt but it did not work.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Define "did not work".

Comment: When I push the push-button switch the servo shaft starts moving but when I leave the push button the servo still keeps on moving. There is some delay before it stops. The delay is variable.

Comment: That's not "did not work", that's "did not behave as expected". And code is required in order to fix that.

Comment: Well you can say that it did not behave as expected. I didn't find proper words. Right now I don't have the code. I will post in the afternoon.

Comment: That program worked. I had made some improper hardware connections. I am posting the code in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

The program worked, I had made some improper hardware connections. Here is the working code:

```
// Program to use External (Hardware) Interrupts of AVR Microcontroller (ATmega16)
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>

/***** Function To Initialize Ports*****/
void init_ports()
{
    DDRA = 0xFF;
    PORTA = 0x55;
}

/***** Function To Initialize Interrupts*****/
void init_interrupts()
{
    cli();  //Disable Global Interrupts
    GICR =(1<<INT0);    //Set Bit6 of GICR to unmask INT0 interrupt.
    MCUCR =(0<<ISC00);  //Configuring MCUCR for Rising Edge interrupt for INT0
    sei();  //Enable Global Interrupts
}

/***** Interrupt Service Routine For INT0*****/
ISR (INT0_vect)
{
    PORTA=~PORTA;
    OCR1A=OCR1A+1;
    _delay_ms(100);
    if(OCR1A==305)
    {   OCR1A=65;
        _delay_ms(200);
    }
}


/***** Main Function *****/
int main(void)
{

//Configure TIMER1
    TCCR1A|=(1<<COM1A1)|(1<<COM1B1)|(1<<WGM11);         //NON Inverted PWM
    TCCR1B|=(1<<WGM13)|(1<<WGM12)|(1<<CS11)|(1<<CS10);  //PRESCALER=64 MODE 14(FAST PWM)

    ICR1=2499;  //fPWM=50Hz (Period = 20ms Standard).

    DDRD|=(1<<PD4)|(1<<PD5);    //PWM Pins as Out
    OCR1A=65;
    init_ports();
    while(1)
    {
        init_interrupts();
    }
}
```

Comment: #include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

Comment: Huge busy-wait loops (_delay_ms) in an ISR is not generally advised. There's also no need to loop the interrupt enabling. This program doesn't really have any advantage from using interrupts; if you do want this functionality in parallel with other code, it's better to use the timer overflow to count the wait times. You could also sleep in the main loop, but the power difference is negligible compared to a servo.